# @click event on a dynamic list of components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm having trouble getting a click event to emit or be captured by Vue when I have a @click event on a v-for list of components.

I have dynamic component can contain a series of other components, with a v-for loop like so:

```
<component v-for="(component, index) in components"
        v-bind:is="component"
        v-bind:key="index"
        @click="sayHi()">
</component>
```

And the components data looks like:

```
data() {
    components: ['Foo', 'Bar'];
}
```

And the method is simply an `sayHi() { alert('hi') }` on the same top-level component (method is not on the children Foo or Bar).

However it seems that the method is never called? I've tried a bunch of different ways and implementations but cannot get the method to fire.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `native` modifier to your event listener if you are attaching a a native event listener to a custom component.

```
   @click.native="sayHi()"
```

Comment: Oh yup, that did it. Thank you! I've actually used the modifier before too, can't believe I forgot about it haha.